# Google Sheets - googlefinance not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I have one google sheet using googlefinance function on multiple stocks. It was working fine until this morning. Now, googlefinace is not giving output for all stocks and giving output for only some of the stocks. Please share, if is anyone else facing the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

I am experiencing the same issue. For some symbols I am getting #N/A, and for others I am getting ridiculous values.

Looks like there is a thread here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/W-vvAbH8nMo

And to upvote this bug for Google to see, you can go here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76403135

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using legacy currency calculations such as

```
=B2*round(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPUSD","price",date(2019,9,3)),2,2),2)
```

which give me "Google Finance Internal Error".

Issue only goes away if I close the tab on Chrome (or Brave in my case) go back to my Drive and open the sheet again.

Answer (score -2):

"Your stocks" is not working for me on Google Finance.  It stopped working yesterday afternoon, and I have been using Yahoo Finance since then.